# Подключить JavaScript и CSS в JSP файл

Tags: jsp

Как подключить CSS в JSP файл, никак не могу, не находит ресурсы?

```
<script src=style.css"></script>
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте такой вариант:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%@include file="/WEB-INF/js/knockout-3.3.0.js"%>
</script>

<style>
    <%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/style.css"%>
</style>
```